# ImportError: No module named 'requests.exceptions'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Super new to coding and i'm trying to learn Python. I have used Anaconda to manage packages, etc. I typically update Anaconda/conda in cmd with commands such as `conda update conda` or `conda update anaconda`

As of late, when using these commands, it comes up with a message: "ImportError: No module named 'Requests.exceptions'" followed by "Import Error: cannot import name 'Session'" Please see below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 171, in main
    activate.main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\activate.py", line 181, in main
    from ..install import symlink_conda
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .core.package_cache import rm_fetched  # NOQA
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ..gateways.download import download
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, HTTPError, InvalidSchema, SSLError
ImportError: No module named 'requests.exceptions'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 179, in main
    return handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 634, in handle_exception
    print_unexpected_error_message(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 596, in print_unexpected_error_message
    stderrlogger.info(get_main_info_str(get_info_dict()))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 162, in get_info_dict
    from ..connection import user_agent
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from requests import Session, __version__ as REQUESTS_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session'
```

I've tried using commands like `pip install requests` but it says that it has already says "Requirement already satisfied and lists locations where it is installed (i am guessing).

At this point I can't even get a response back from conda commands like `conda info --envs`. It doesn't do anything when i type that in.

If i need to uninstall conda/anaconda i will but am i just missing a simple fix?

Thanks friends!

Comment: try this: pip install -U requests https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5862

Comment: That returned a message that it is already up-to-date: 
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install -U requests
Requirement already up-to-date: requests in c:\users\andrew\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>` ... etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should install requests with conda if you plan to use conda as your python environment.

`conda install requests`

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! When i tried that the same import errors came up as before: ImportError: No module named 'requests.exceptions

Comment: How are you running your python script? can you add more details to your question? Be very explicit.

Comment: I apologize if l don't understand the question correctly. I am just running a command prompt on windows as an administrator to try and update conda and anaconda. I believe the PATH is set so that when i am in the command prompt, i can run `conda update conda` it runs and updates.

Comment: So when you run your python file, do you do `conda <python file>`?

Comment: To be honest, i've not even gotten that far, I am looking to use an IDE like Pycharm in the future, but up until this point i've not really run any .py files on my machine..